# AWS Java application. С чего начать

Tags: amazon-web-services

Хочу запустить Java сервер на Amazon Web Services(AWS), а не на хостинге (проект образовательный для себя). Но не совсем понимаю, верно ли я думаю: то что можно сделать на хостинге, можно сделать на AWS. А именно:

1) Запустить Java сервер
2) Подключить MySQL
3) Подключить файловое хранилище

Какой минимальный набор сервисов AWS необходим?

Есть ли какие либо уроки для старта, для новичков с нулевым знанием AWS? Т.к. на русском толковой информации я не нашел, на офф. сайте разобраться сложно (слабый английский, но с переводчиком пытаюсь).

Comment: Сначала запустите у себя на локально. Если довольны будете результатом, можете переносить хоть на хостинг, хоть на AWS

Comment: @ArchDemon Локально все есть, с хостингом опыт был. Сейчас хочу разобраться с AWS.

Comment: Докером пользуетесь? Сперва заливаете все в Docker локально, тестируете. Потом переносите докер-контейнер в aws.

Comment: Докером на пользовался, читал но не пользовался. Частая практика - использование докера?

Comment: Использование Докера сейчас является нормой. Плюс тут в том, что настройка всего окружения проводится локально на вашем компьютере. А затем на хостинг заливается уже полностью настроенный контейнер. И всё всегда работает. Ну, почти...